# How to write my C++ function so I can call it from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, c++-cli

I have C++ code. That code contains Windows mobile GPS enable/disable functionality. I want to call that method from C# code, that means when the user clicks on a button, C# code should call into C++ code.

This is the C++ code for enabling the GPS functionality:

```
#include "cppdll.h"

void Adder::add()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
  HANDLE hDrv = CreateFile(TEXT("FNC1:"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
  if (0 == DeviceIoControl(hDrv, IOCTL_WID_GPS_ON, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL))
  {
     RETAILMSG(1, (L"IOCTL_WID_RFID_ON Failed !! \r\n")); return;
  }
     CloseHandle(hDrv);

 return (x+y);
}
```

And this is the header file `cppdll.h`:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Adder
{
  public:
   Adder(){;};
  ~Adder(){;};
 void add();
};
```

How can I call that function using C#?

Please, can anybody help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'll give you an example.

You should declare your C++ functions for export like so (assuming recent MSVC compiler):

```
extern "C"             //No name mangling
__declspec(dllexport)  //Tells the compiler to export the function
int                    //Function return type     
__cdecl                //Specifies calling convention, cdelc is default, 
                       //so this can be omitted 
test(int number){
    return number + 1;
}
```

And compile your C++ project as a dll library. Set your project target extension to .dll, and Configuration Type to Dynamic Library (.dll).

[image]

Then, in C# declare:

```
public static class NativeTest
{
    private const string DllFilePath = @"c:\pathto\mydllfile.dll";

    [DllImport(DllFilePath , CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private extern static int test(int number);

    public static int Test(int number)
    {
        return test(number);
    }
}
```

Then you can call your C++ test function, as you would expect. Note that it may get a little tricky once you want to pass strings, arrays, pointers, etc. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741206/using-arrays-and-pointers-in-c-sharp-with-c-dll) SO question.

Comment: I would still do this: #define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

Comment: @Quandary sure, whatever floats your boat. I like to specify calling convention explicitly, so I need a more advanced macro to take the type parameter, and I generally try to avoid *more advanced macros*, as they are, I'm sure you know - evil.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have edited code.It giving error.I have changed configuration also. Please help me. `\GpsCppToDll.cpp(2) : warning C4627: '#include "GpsCppToDll.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>        Add directive to 'stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>.\GpsCppToDll.cpp(15) : fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?`

Comment: It looks like you have selected to use precompiled headers when you created your project, and then forgot to include it in one of your .cpp files. You could just add a #include stdafx.h (at the very top) in your GpsCppToDll .cpp file.

Comment: Can you please look at this question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410197/cant-find-pinvoke-dll-bug

Comment: @Gleno does this solution work with unmanaged C++? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/935713/839501) answer when trying to figure out how to call C++ code from C#. The link explains how to create a managed C++ wrapper around your unmanaged C++ code. Is that not needed anymore? Or is the wrapper still needed to deal with more complicated data types?

Comment: @Dan, this is a more portable solution; but both have merits. If you are familiar and comfortable with C++/CLI and your work permits you to restrict parts of your code to C++/CLI by all means use it, because it will be easier for any nontrivial amount of work.

Comment: @Dan oh and by the way, this method is not suitable if you C++ code throws. Then you are much better off with C++/CLi to C# approach.

Comment: @Gleno Thanks so much for the response I will take this into account when trying to accomplish my task to port unmanged C++ apps to web through C#