# Can't find PInvoke DLL - BUG?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, windows-mobile

I have got Windows mobile GPS third party application.That is C++ code which code contain GPS automatic enabling/disabling facility.

I want to make dll.  That also i did. When the user click invoice (C# code) GPS (C++) have to find.

This is my source Code GPS.cpp

```
      extern "C"      //No name mangling
      __declspec(dllexport) 
      #include "GPS.h"

      #include "stdafx.h"
      #include "RF PWR.h"
      #include "RF PWRDlg.h"
      #include "widioctl.h"

     #ifdef _DEBUG
     #define new DEBUG_NEW
     #endif

      void CaptureGPS()
     {
    HANDLE hDrv = CreateFile(TEXT("FNC1:"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                            0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (0 == DeviceIoControl(hDrv, IOCTL_WID_GPS_ON, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL))
{
    RETAILMSG(1, (L"IOCTL_WID_RFID_ON Failed !! \r\n")); return;
}
CloseHandle(hDrv);
}
```

& this is the GPS.h

```
class Adder
 {
    public:
       Adder(){;};
       ~Adder(){;};
       void CaptureGPS();
 };
```

This is my Source : http://pastie.org/3436376

It say `can't find entry point  CaptureGPS in PInvoke RF PWF.dll`

Please anybody help me out this..

What is the issues...

Answer (score 2):

### Let me explain first, what you've written

```
extern "C"      //No name mangling
__declspec(dllexport) 
#include "GPS.h"
```

will expand after preprocessing to

```
extern "C"      //No name mangling
__declspec(dllexport) 
class Adder
{
    public:
       Adder(){;};
       ~Adder(){;};
       void CaptureGPS();
};
```

It means, you are:

- attempting to make `class Adder` `C`-style struct (and while it is not possible due to `class Adder` is not POD, `extern "C"` simply ignored)
- attempting export a variable of `class Adder`, if it would defined after `class` definition, like:

  ```
  extern "C"      //No name mangling
  __declspec(dllexport) 
  class Adder
  {
      public:
         Adder(){;};
         ~Adder(){;};
         void CaptureGPS();
  } variable;
  ```

  But it is no any `variable` defined, so `__declspec(dllexport)` simply ignored.

Note, that you declared some methods in `class Adder` but not defined them. It is ok, while you do not try to use `class Adder`. Also note, that your `void CaptureGPS()` has nothing with `void Adder::CaptureGPS()`, it is *just separate function*.

### What I think, you should do

It seems, you want just export `void CaptureGPS();`

If it is, you should add to your header file:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void CaptureGPS();
```

Than, `CaptureGPS()` will be exported and you will be able to call it with `pinvoke`

Comment: Still I am getting same error message... `an't find entry point CaptureGPS in PInvoke RF PWF.dll` .The source File name is `GPS.cpp` but project name is `RF PRF` . Is there any issue?

Comment: You should provide some additional info, if you compile your lib correctly, function should be crated and exported. Now you could examine export table of your dll

Comment: Wait! You cannot compile your `dll`. First, `#include "stdafx.h"` before `#include "gps.h"` in your cpp, then rebuild project.

Comment: @Piraba,  well, it something wired and sure not connected with this question. I am a not MSVC errors guru, if _rebuilding_ project does not help, try asking this problem as a separate question.

Comment: Ok . I will ask & post it here also

Comment: Probably related to name mangling. Use peinfo to check the export names on the DLL: http://www.pazera-software.com/products/peinfo/

Comment: @Polynomial, to check export names of dll, you should have dll. but it fails to compile for now.

Comment: This is same question with error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412975/call-c-code-from-c-sharp-error

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN has an article that covers writing DLL function for P/Invoking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446532.aspx) and checking the exported names via dumpbin.  It was written specifically for the Compact Framework, so it's very relevant to what you're doing.

That said, why are you creating a DLL for this anyway?  Why not just P/Invoke CreateFile, DeviceIoControl and CloseHandle directly from your C# app?  There's another [MSDN article that covers using Stream Interface Drivers from managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446570.aspx) in the Compact Framework as well.

Comment: -1. In case links are ever killed, like these were, it's SO policy to *summarize* the content here, not just link off to it. This answer is now pretty useless.