# How can I call a function from C# app in a C++/CLI DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, command-line-interface

I've written a simple C++/CLI DLL that has 2 public static methods:

```
namespace GetMscVerLib
{
    public ref class CGetMscVer
    {
        static System::Int32 GetCompilerVersion ();
        static System::Int32 GetCompilerFullVersion ();
    };
}
```

I'm trying to call these methods from a C# console app in the same solution but the compiler doesn't recognize the methods and shows an error that says that the methods don't "exist in the current context":

```
namespace Get_MSC_VER
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Int32 i32CompilerVersion     = CGetMscVer.GetCompilerVersion ();
            Int32 i32CompilerFullVersion = CGetMscVer.GetCompilerFullVersion ();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct syntax?  (online searches have produced pages of irrelevant links with some of the search keywords, assuming DllImport or COM).  This seems like it should be quite a simple matter but finding it is not.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I call to a C++ function from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407616/how-can-i-call-to-a-c-function-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Whats the error youre getting? You should be able to use it like any other .Net library.

Comment: Try
 `CGetMscVer myObj = new CGetMscVer(); 
myObj.GetCompilerVersion ();`

Comment: 1: The error is "error CS1061: 'GetMscVerLib.CGetMscVer' does not contain a definition for 'GetCompilerVersion' and no extension method 'GetCompilerVersion' accepting a first argument of type 'GetMscVerLib.CGetMscVer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: 2. I've written the methods as static.  When I change them to non-static and use an instance of the class I get the error "error CS0117: 'GetMscVerLib.CGetMscVer' does not contain a definition for 'GetCompilerVersionStatic'"

Comment: Sorry my c++ isnt great, They may need to be marked as public methods. It is picking up your type okay just not the methods.

Comment: Also, looking up the errors online hasn't been productive because the only responses assume calling from C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Because the methods are private by default c# wont allow you to access them.

```
namespace GetMscVerLib
{
    public ref class CGetMscVer
    {
      public:
        static System::Int32 GetCompilerVersion ();
        static System::Int32 GetCompilerFullVersion ();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need build your C++ program, you will get dll. Then you should create method with the same return value and add `extern` key word add `DllImport` attribute to your method. In your example method will look like this:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var version = GetCompilerVersion();
        var fullVersion = GetCompilerFullVersion();
    }
    
    [DllImport("yourDllName.dll")]
    public static extern int GetCompilerVersion();
    
    [DllImport("yourDllName.dll")]
    public static extern int GetCompilerFullVersion();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, keeping everything static.

```
// C++/CLI DLL

namespace GetMscVerLib
{
    public ref class CGetMscVer abstract sealed
    {
    public:
        static System::Int32 GetCompilerVersion();
    };
}
```

```
// C# assembly that references the C/C++ DLL

namespace Get_MSC_VER
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Int32 i32CompilerVersion = GetMscVerLib.CGetMscVer.GetCompilerVersion();
        }
    }
}
```